# How to extract the full content from a partial content rss

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, rss-reader, rss2

I am working on a PHP project. The goal (in a simple lang) is to read an RSS feed, and get the title, full content, and media (video and/or images) from it, and post it in a wordpress blog. (The customer wants to use some sources that are open for sharing and use them for auto posting in his blog)

I successfully could extract the title, content and images or videos and post them in wordpress. However, there are some problems:

1) I can only extract the media if they are included in the RSS.
2) I cannot extract the full text of the content if the RSS is a partial content RSS.

So, is there any solution to be able to access the original content from RSS and extract the full text content and media if available?

Comment: That depends entirely on what the rss xml looks like

Comment: But I think there should be a way to access the full content, for example there are some website which give you the full content from a rss like: http://fulltextrssfeed.com/ So there should be a way, no matter how the rss looks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RSS provider decides if the full text is exported or not. So if it exports just the partial content, you may have to get the full content of the link by curl(or others) and try to figure out where the full content is.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide a link to the rss feed I will update my answer to tell you precisely. This can only be determined on a case by case. An example of a reader can be found here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_rss_reader.asp obviously with modern techniques you can do a lot better.

Comment: Yeah, it works great. But I already have developed it until this point. as an example lets say MSNBC NEWS RSS, it's rss is partial content, so I need a way to get the full content from the original post somehow.

Comment: Glad that worked great. To get the full content you need to find access to the actual RSS feed. In the case of MSNBC News you can be sure it is a password protected file so what you want is impossible without hacking (which no one here will tell you how to do even if they knew). Sorry :(

Comment: No, That's not the case... I just want to get some posts from sites that provide rss with mentioning the source of the posts... I'm pretty sure that there should be a way (No HACKING!!!). the reason that sites provide partial rss is mostly because of bandwidth... but there are plenty of sites that let their rss to be shared...