# how to get news full content from rss feed in j2ee

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, rss

I am developing a site which is supposed to get the news content of other sites, something like [this](http://www.newsnow.co.uk/h/). but without redirecting to the host for reading the news content.

now the problem is that I don't know what is the best way to get the content completely. I know that I can use RSS feed for each site but it has only a short description of each news not the whole story. I have also read the related questions in SO like these:
[How to get the full content from the rss feed in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646297/how-to-get-the-full-content-from-the-rss-feed-in-javascript)
[How to extract the full content from a partial content rss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653494/how-to-extract-the-full-content-from-a-partial-content-rss)
but none of them solved my problem .

now I wanna ask what is the best way to get the whole content of news from different sites if it is necessary to go directly to them?
I am sorry because of bad english and if my question is not clear enough I can explain it even more
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use web scraping library like [boilerpipe](https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/) to extract content from news sites, but scraping breaks easily(if the target site changes layout for example) and there might be [legal issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping#Legal_issues) in extracting full content from other sites and displaying in yours.

Edit: I tried [boilerpipe api demo](http://boilerpipe-web.appspot.com/) and the library seems very smart at extracting articles from web pages.

Comment: thanks it really helped me. do you now any way to get just the main html content of an html file? no tags, no comments just the pure content.

Comment: Try [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). Here's one question and answer that might help you: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943734/jsoup-strip-all-formatting-and-link-tags-keep-text-only). For example if you know the css selector that has the main html content, you could use jsoup to pull text from it.

Comment: I appreciate if you can help me in this question too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674345/how-to-replace-some-tags-and-remove-others-with-line-break-in-j2ee